# rear passenger door lock

Tags: honda, locks, crv

I have a 2007 CRV.  I had all the locks replaced by a Honda dealer two years ago at no cost to me due to a history of issues with this model. Now the rear door is "working" but makes a terrible sound for about 2 to 3 seconds when  it locks or unlocks.  Very annoying.  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you attempted anything yet, like lubricate the lock mechanism?

Comment: I'd certainly be talking to the dealer about replacing the shoddy locks again, or fixing what they did wrong.